# Test Management Tool for Cucumber and BDD test cases

Tags: test-management

We want to maintain a single test management tool for all the **cucumber** tests and the manual test cases (test cases also written in BDD format).

Will create the manual test cycles for execution as well as daily automation jobs results must be integrated to the test management tool.

I come across Speclog, mainly that is for SpecFlow.

Can anyone suggest the test management tool for these?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the tools to manage cucumber tests is [Hiptest](https://hiptest.com/).

New features are added all the time. One of the features is that You can export Your test cases to code (in many lanugaes - python, C#, js, ruby etc.) with function stubs so you can quite quickly start to implement tests.

Support is always willing to help.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I am going through about the tool.

Answer (score 2):

[TestRail](http://www.gurock.com/testrail) is an option. I used it in the past. The management of testcases is great once you get familiar with how it operates. You can set up test suites and then test runs, and include the relevant test cases, reusing them for various projects for example.

They have an API which you can hook into. We had a Jenkins job which would kick off the automated tests, and "upload" the results (including log file contents, images, etc.) in real time to TestRail. TestRail has good reporting features. Once it was set up, it worked really well and was fairly reliable.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I am going through about the tool.

Answer (score 1):

You can also have a look a Test Collab, test management tool. [Here is the link](http://testcollab.com).

You can see their [API from here.](https://api.testcollab.com/)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, ours is a startup and we are less than 15 testers. Mainly we are looking for open source or if commercial then cost-effective.